# Why is this p-channel MOSFET blinker not blinking?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, blink

I'm not a professional electronics person, just enthusiastic about it so my knownledge is limited. I first tried this with a n-channel mosfet, and worked well:

[image]

But it switches negative, and I need a positive switch, so tried this with a p-channel mosfet but didn't work:

[image]

In fact, I need the circuit to be in series between the battery and the bulb, which is grounded.

**Requirement:** the circuit should blink grounded bulb by turning on/off positive to the bulb, indefinitely until circuit gets its positive feed disconnected. Like a car's turn lights flasher relay... something like this:

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE**

So...for the sake of science :) I experimented with this (pmos):

[image]

It starts blinking, not a full on/off but about half way (LTspice sim shows 12v then down to 7v, then a new cycle). However on each cycle it blinks less and less until the bulb remains ON.

Comment: what does this mean? ... `it switches negative`

Comment: @jsotola positive is directly from battery to bulb, negative is applied to Source and comes out from Drain. The capacitors do the on/off trick by discharging negative to Source...I "think" :)

Comment: @AramAlvarez, What are you trying to achieve here? Do you want the bulb to turn ON a certain time after the 12V supply is switched ON and then stay ON till 12V supply is present? Please state all the requirements of your circuit.

Comment: I've never seen this one-transistor blinker before. Does it really work? If it does work I imagine it's pretty sensitive to what kind of MOSFET you use, bulb current, RC values, etc

Comment: This switch doesn't know whether it's a negative or a positive switch. If the N-channel version works it should work on either side of the bulb.

Comment: @user253751 well the n-channel version works well, but I can't use it because the bulb is currently grounded in the actual circuit, I can only turn it on/off using its positive feed wire; can´t touch it´s wire to ground.

Comment: @AramAlvarez This circuit doesn't know whether it's in the positive wire or the negative wire, therefore, it should be fine to put it in either one. (Assuming it works at all. I am surprised it does)

Comment: @user253751 If I use a n-channel mosfet the bulb should be placed between circuit and ground. I need the circuit to be placed before bulb to ground, so it controls the + to the bulb. Like: battery -> circuit -> bulb -> ground and NOT battery -> bulb -> circuit -> ground. Since the bulb is already grounded and can't change that, but its + connection is ok to tweak. The bulb is actually spot welded to the device ground and gets a steady + via a wire to light it on. I need to blink it.

Comment: @AramAlvarez It would work just as well either way around. The circuit doesn't know which way around it is. It can't tell.

Comment: @user253751 what do you suggest I should do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your NMOS circuit seems to work just as well with the lamp from source to GND. Here's the simulation (but using 10 uF capacitors to reduce simulation time).

[image: NMOS flasher with lamp grounded]

I found that the circuit needs to have power connected quickly, so here is a simulation with 100 uF capacitors, and it starts flashing in about 1 second.

[image: NMOS flasher with 100 uF]

Comment: Indeed, the n-channel mosfet circuit works...but as I stated above, I need it to use a p-channel mosfet instead

Comment: Can you explain *why* you must use a p-channel MOSFET? The circuit I simulated uses a negative grounded battery *and* the lamp is also grounded. AFAIK that was your requirement. How does this NMOS circuit *not* do what you want it to do?

Comment: sorry sir, yes you are right. I installed LTspice and could replicate your simulation. Thanks a heap!